# requiring a directory rather than a js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I come across a piece code like this in an index.js file:

```js
exports = module.exports = require("./src")
```

Not sure what the `exports = module.exports` bit means.
And not sure what it means to import an entire directory `/src`.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/

Comment: doc does not mention requiring a directory

Comment: “ An extra note: if the filename passed to require is actually a directory, it will first look for package.json in the directory and load the file referenced in the main property. Otherwise, it will look for an index.js.”

Comment: thanks. that clears it up. what about this bit `exports = module.exports`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

These are solutions for your questions, from first to second (in order).

1. Most likely setting the variable `exports` to `module.exports`.
2. Importing a default file in the folder (e.g. `index.js`) if specified or not.

---

**1. What does the `exports` variable define?**

From [Dave Meehan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/327598/dave-meehan), a few corrections made:

*Comment #1*

> Your explanation of 1 is incorrect. If they were separate statements as illustrated, exports would equal the previous value of `module.exports`, and `module.exports` would equal the return value of `require`. Chaining them together sets both `exports` and `module.exports` to the value returned by `require`. It's not clear why someone would want to do that, but they did.

*Comment #2*

> We should be very careful in interpreting what the result might be in such a statement as its dependent on whether the variables `export` and `module` (with/without property exports) already exists, and whether we are using `strict` mode. There's a number of other SO posts that expand on "chaining assignment".

<sup>Note: I am also mildly confused on this line, so this is my educated guess. Feel free to correct me in the comments, or by editing my post.</sup>

**Note: This solution is incorrect. Please see [Dave Meehan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/327598/dave-meehan)'s comments on corrections for this solution.**

This line most likely can be also spread into multiple lines, like so.

```js
exports = module.exports;
module.exports = require("./src");
```

Basically, it is just making a variable called `exports`, and setting that to `module.exports`.

This same thing can be done using object destructing too.

```js
const { exports } = module;
```

This will simply get the `exports` key from `module`, and make a new variable called `exports`.

---

**2. How do you `require` a folder?**

Technically, Node isn't importing an entire folder. Basically, it is checking for a default file in the directory.

There are two cases in how Node.js will check for a file.

1. If the `main` property is defined in `package.json`, it will look for that file in the `/src` directory.

   ```json
   {
     "main": "app.js"
   }
   ```

   If the `package.json`, was like that, for instance, then it would search for `/src/app.js`.
2. If the `main` property isn't defined in `package.json`, then it will by default look for a file named `index.js`. So, it would import `/src/index.js`.

---

**Summary**

In summary, these are the solutions to your questions.

1. Most likely setting the variable `exports` to `module.exports`.
2. Importing a default file in the folder (e.g. `index.js`) if specified or not.

This should help clear your confusion.

Comment: Your explanation of 1 is incorrect.  If they were separate statements as illustrated, exports would equal the previous value of module.exports, and module.exports would equal the return value of require.  Chaining them together sets both exports and module.exports to the value returned by require.  It's not clear why someone would want to do that, but they did.

Comment: We should be very careful in interpretting what the result might be in such a statement as its dependent on whether the variables export and module (with/without property exports) already exists, and whether we are using 'strict' mode.  There's a number of other SO posts that expand on "chaining assignment".

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. If you would like, you can edit my post to include the fixes for the mistakes that I have made in my answer.

Comment: Happy for you to do that and add whatever references you feel useful.

Comment: Thanks! I've just quoted you, but you can edit my answer to change it if you wish.

Comment: Thanks, you could click the 'upvote' next to the comments to indicate they were useful ;-)

Comment: I already did when I linked your comments. 